# Could not read from remote github repository

Tags: github

I am trying to push to a github repo but getting an error

```
ERROR: Permission to microsoft/playwright.git denied to my_user.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Steps I performed:

1- Successfully Cloned the repo using ssh `git@github.com:microsoft/playwright.git`

2- But when I am trying to push a branch to it I am received an authentication error

3- Prior to cloning I created a new SSH key and added it [as per instructions [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) ]

4- I also tested my ssh connection using `ssh -T git@github.com` and it shows success

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.xx.xxx.xxx' to the list of known hosts.
Hi user! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

5- I also re-cloned the repo after restarting my computer but I still am not able to push to the playwright repo

Comment: Do you have a permission to push to the `microsoft/playwright`? Basically we fork it to our repository, create a branch and push to our forked repository and then create a pull request to their repository.

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk Okay, I will try your approach and post the results. Thank you

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk It worked! After forking and then pushing a branch worked and I am able to create a PR at `microsoft/playwright` can you please post this as an answer so I can accept it if thats ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to the [Fork a repo](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo) which describes as the following: -

> A fork is a copy of a repository. Forking a repository allows you to freely experiment with changes without affecting the original project.
>
> Most commonly, forks are used to either propose changes to someone else's project or to use someone else's project as a starting point for your own idea. You can fork a repository to create a copy of the repository and make changes without affecting the upstream repository.

To collaborate with the public repo, basically we will do the following steps: -

- Fork the repo to our own. (in this case, we fork the `microsoft/playwright`)
- Within the forked repo

  - Make a change/improvement.
  - Push to the forked repo branch.
- If it looks good, then create a pull request back to the upstream to notify them to review and approve.

*Sidebar*

We may visit the following GitHub documents as a guidance.

- [Fork a repo](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo)
- [Creating and deleting branches within your repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository)
- [About pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests)
- [Creating a pull request from a fork](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork)